# python wont let me import modules

Tags: python-3.x, import, pycharm, python-module

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF5NO.png)

[image]

It just keeps greying it out when i go to import statistics, math, random or anything -- it shows up in my project interpreter, so im not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Greyed out just means that the name has not been used in the code below. The colour is to indicate an *unused* import.

It does not mean you can not import the module.

Once you actually reference the imported module in the code below, it should become colored as usual.